# How to decrease the output time of covariance function

Tags: python, performance, covariance

I have written a function for covariance matrix and the output I am getting is correct but the problem with the code is, it's taking too much time for high dimension dataset.

Could you please help me to modify the code below to take less time for output?

```
def cov_variance(norm_data,mean_of_mat):
    col = len(norm_data)
    row = len(norm_data[0])
    out =[]
    i = 0 
    sum_of_covar = 0
    freezrow  = 0
    flag = 1
    while flag<=len(mean_of_mat):
        for r in range(row):
            for c in range(col):
                sum_of_covar+=(((norm_data[c][freezrow])-mean_of_mat[freezrow])*\
                               ((norm_data[c][r])-mean_of_mat[i]))
                freezrow=freezrow
            out.append(sum_of_covar)
            i+=1
            sum_of_covar=0
            freezrow=freezrow
        flag+=1
        freezrow+=1
        i=0
    out1 = map(lambda x : x/col-1,out)
    cov_variance_output = reshape(out1,row)
    return cov_variance_output
```

Comment: Is `norm_data` a list? Something from numpy? Why roll your own?

Comment: yes norm_data is a list, it is the output of StandardScaler which I implement it by myself i didn't used numpy for that .

Comment: I wonder if using an array instead of a list might be better. Some kind of profiling might help too. How big does it need to get to slow down? Is this a linear slow down, or quadratic or what?

Comment: Even I changed list to array still it is too slow, it is quadratic slow down. I don't know how to modify the code to make it quicker .

Answer (score 0):

Like doctorlove already said, don't implement your own. It will almost certainly be slower and/or less versatile (speaking from my own experience).

I tried commenting with this info but my rep is too low. You can find information on calculating covariance matrices with numpy here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html

Comment: As doctorlove said, please say why it's quicker? please note I know how to implement covariance with numpy but here I want to know why my code is too slow.